# Want to expose AD over IIS in Windows server 2012

Tags: active-directory, iis, windows-server-2012

Is there any way or new technology introduced in Windows Server 2012 to expose Active Directory Services hosted on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring about publishing an ADFS service? If yes, have you considered the Web Application Gateway role in Windows Server 2012 R2? 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/applicationproxyblog/archive/2014/10/01/introducing-the-next-version-of-web-application-proxy.aspx